# Minecraft PE Other area of the map is not loading

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image: The cut out part of the world]

For some reason my world in Minecraft PE doesn't load the whole area instead half of it is just an empty void but my other buildings are still lost in the empty void. There's an invisible wall blocking me going to the empty void. Version is 0.10.5 and this is an infinite world. I used the flat world seed

Comment: Could you take a screenshot please?

Comment: Could you please provide more information? E.g. Version, Screenshot, world type etc

Comment: Could it be the render distance? http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Render_Distance

Comment: It can't be the render distance because I can't even go to that area. There is like an invibisible wall blocking me.

Answer (score -1):

Try disconnecting and reconnecting or refresh your app. It happens to me all the time ;)